# Delimit a column in R based on 2 characters

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe in R that contains values such as

```
C22/00556,
C21/00445,
B22/00111,
C22-00679, etc.
```

I would like to split this into 2 columns named `initial` and `number`. The delimiter being "-" or "/".
As a result I would expect a column containing C22, C21, B22, etc and another column containing 00556, 00445 etc.

I am trying to use the separate function but I am struggling with the `sep=` part.
I have tried using `sep= c("/","-")` but this is not working and throws an error.

Comment: the string for " slash or hyphen" is, I think, `"/|-"` - to explain, the "pattern" variable shouldn't be a vector of patterns, but a single string expressing the full logic at once.

Comment: In your case, in `separate`, you don't need to specify `sep`, since it automatically use non-alphanum characters as separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `separate` from `tidyr` by `/` or (|) `-` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("C22/00556", "C21/00445", "B22/00111", "C22-00679"))

library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate(V1, c("initial", "number"), sep = "/|-")
#>   initial number
#> 1     C22  00556
#> 2     C21  00445
#> 3     B22  00111
#> 4     C22  00679
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
read.table(text = chartr("/", "-", df$V1), sep = "-", header = FALSE, 
    col.names = c("initial", "number"), colClasses = "character")
  initial number
1     C22  00556
2     C21  00445
3     B22  00111
4     C22  00679
```